# How to refer Pipeline Run from resourcetemplates of TriggerTemplate

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

I have the below pipeline run

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: ft-common-run
  namespace: fetebird-common
spec:
  pipelineRef:
    name: ft-common
  podTemplate:
    securityContext:
      fsGroup: 65532
  workspaces:
    - name: shared-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: fetebird-common-pvc
  params:
    - name: REPO_URL
      value: git@bitbucket.org:anandjaisy/common.git
    - name: GRADLE_IMAGE
      value: docker.io/library/gradle:jdk17-alpine@sha256:e80d3108c319eaeef966eefdfd075fdaa44201c8fb6730532a16555426c61dbd
  taskRunSpecs:
    - pipelineTaskName: git-clone
      taskServiceAccountName: git-service-account
    - pipelineTaskName: gradle-clean-build-publish
      taskServiceAccountName: gcp-service-account
```

In the below trigger template

```
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerTemplate
metadata:
  name: bitbucket-trigger-template
  namespace: fetebird-common
spec:
  params:
    - name: REPO_URL
      value: git@bitbucket.org:anandjaisy/common.git
    - name: GRADLE_IMAGE
      value: docker.io/library/gradle:jdk17-alpine@sha256:e80d3108c319eaeef966eefdfd075fdaa44201c8fb6730532a16555426c61dbd
  resourcetemplates:
   // How can I refer pipeline run here
```

How can I refer the above pipeline run in the resource templates of TriggerTemplate

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the official documentation for the [TriggerTemplate](https://tekton.dev/docs/triggers/triggertemplates/), it is currently not possible to reference a PipelineRun in a TriggerTemplate. The PipelineRun component was not design to be reusable like the Pipeline component. The Pipeline component is already kind of a template used by a PipelineRun.

When a PipelineRun is created, it is executed immediately and create the necessary resources for it workspace like a PVC immediately as well. It would not make sense to reuse a already executed PipelineRun, overwriting all logs and outputs of the previous run.

The TriggerTemplate field "resourcetemplates" is self-explanatory, the resource specified there need to be a template and a PipelineRun is not a template. What you are looking for is something like a PipelineRunTemplate component, but this component does not currently exist. You are more than welcome suggest this idea to the Tekton official github repo [discussion page](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/discussions).